# In OpenGL-OpenCL texture interop, how does the PBO receive the data from the texture?

Tags: opengl, opencl

Most examples on PBOs on the web are about making CPU-GPU transfers asynchronous.

I'm trying to use PBOs for something else - for OpenGL-OpenCL interop, as explained in [this tutorial](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/opencl-and-opengl-interoperability-tutorial.html). Quote from there:

> [...] Creating an intermediate (staging) Pixel-Buffer-Object for the OpenGL texture via clCreateFromGLBuffer, updating the buffer with OpenCL, and copying the results back to the texture.

The tutorial explains I need to create the PBO as follows:

```
GLuint pbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
//specifying the buffer size
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, width * height * sizeof(cl_uchar4), …);
```

I have replaced the ellipsis with `NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY`, as I don't want to send any data from the host.

Here's the createPbo function I ended up with:

```
void createPbo(ivec2 sz, int elementSize) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sz.x * sz.y * elementSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

In the rest of my code, I do what the tutorial does, and the code works fine. **The problem is the `glGetTexImage` call: The tutorial doesn't mention it, which means maybe I can skip doing this slow copy? Can I?**

---

Note about my usecase: I'm trying to send **existing** OpenGL texture data into OpenCL, manipulate it there, and then send it back to OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks. I access it like so: `clfftEnqueueTransform(plan, dir, 1, &queue, 0, NULL, NULL, &theBuffer, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `clfftEnqueueTransform`. What is `queue`? Note that the data is still in GPU memory after running `glGetTexImage`. Can `clfftEnqueueTransform` access an OpenGL buffer object? Maybe it can, but it can't access the texture image.

Comment: The data is accessed  with `glMapBuffer`.  Therefor you need to copy the data from the texture image to a buffer. See the answer.

Comment: @httpdigest No. Please don't delet your anser. It is correct and even better than mine. 2 ( different) answers are fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access an image level of an OpenGL texture *directly* in OpenCL without copying (at least not as an explicit API action) as an OpenCL image object via [clCreateFromGLTexture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromGLTexture.html).

The very tutorial you mentioned also mentions this. You don't need a buffer object or a pixel buffer transfer operation.

And, for completeness, since the question was explicitly about how to use GL buffer sharing in OpenCL and then using the GL buffer to update a texture image:

The tutorial you referenced (in Method 2) also covers exactly how to do this. In this case, we do not share a level of the GL texture but we share a GL buffer object as a CL buffer object:

(the following is more or less a direct copy/paste of that tutorial's sources)

First, create the OpenGL buffer object that we want to share with OpenCL and that we will later use to update a texture image with PBO transfer:

```c
GLuint pbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
//specifying the buffer size
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, width * height * sizeof(cl_uchar4), …);
```

Next, if you want to initialize the GL buffer object with a level of your original GL texture, you first *need* to PBO copy that image into the GL buffer object:

```c
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texFormat, texType, 0);
```

This will PBO-copy the GL texture's first level into the GL buffer object.

Next, share the GL buffer in OpenCL:

```c
mem = clCreateFromGLBuffer(g_context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, pbo,  NULL);
```

Then, acquire the ownership of the shared GL/CL buffer object via `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects()`, execute the kernel that updates the CL buffer content, and release the ownership via `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects()`.

And last, update an OpenGL texture (currently bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D`) with PBO transfer out of the GL buffer object:

```c
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about the clCreateFromGLTexture approach. I should've mentioned that I need the data as a **buffer** (on the OpenCL side), since I'm using a library (clFFT) which doesn't support **images** as input (or output).

Comment: In the rest of your answer, you describe the following algorithm: "1. create GL buffer. 2. send the GL buffer to opencl. 3. acquire ownership, run kernel, release ownership. 4. update the texture". What I'm missing is a "step zero" where you copy the old state of the texture into the GL buffer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot because the data is accessed with buffer [Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) ([`glMapBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml)). You cannot directly map a texture image, but you can map the data store of a buffer object. Therefore you need to copy the data from the texture image into the data store of a buffer.
[`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) carries out the "copying" process (and necessary format and type conversions). It get the data from the texture bound to target `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and stores the data in the buffer bound to target `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using buffer mapping. I'm following "Method 2" from the tutorial (the one that uses clCreateFromGLBuffer).